# join returns nothing

Tags: columns, join

I have two files with columns separated by tab and I want to merge them
**file a01**

```
a=  b=  
c=  d=
e=  f=
g=  h=  i=
j=  k=  l=
m=  n=  0=
```

**file b01**

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
7   8   9
10  11  12
13  14  15
```

**desired output**

```
a=1 b=2
c=3 d=4
e=5 f=6
g=7 h=8 i=9
j=10    k=11    l=12
m=13    n=14    0=15
```

but when I run the command

```
join a01 b01
```

it returns nothing

I don't know what I am doing wrong
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simply not how the `join`command works - it joins *lines* based on a common (matching field) - which your input files don't have.

You could do something like this using `paste` and `awk`:

```
paste a01 b01 | awk '{n=NF; for (i=n/2;i>0;i--) {$i = $i""$(i+n/2); NF--}} 1'
a=1 b=2
c=3 d=4
e=5 f=6
g=7 h=8 i=9
j=10 k=11 l=12
m=13 n=14 0=15
```

Comment: It works fine, thanks for the answer and the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Another possible `awk` solution:

```
paste a01 b01 | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF/2; i++) printf $i $(i+NF/2) (i==int(NF/2) ? RS:FS) }'
```